# Why am I getting a PX.Data.PXLockViolationException when I am try to create an item programmatically?

Tags: acumatica

I have an action button that is taking an item row and creating a new stock item based on that information. Here is the code:

```
public PXAction<CFBSCatalogHeader> ConvertToItem;
[PXButton()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Convert to Item")]
protected void convertToItem()
{
    CFBSCatalogDetail row = Details.Current;
    if (row == null)
        return;

    InventoryItemMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
    graph.Item.Current = graph.Item.Insert();
    graph.Item.Current.InventoryCD = row.VendorPartID;
    graph.Item.Current.Descr = row.Descr;
    graph.Item.Current.ItemClassID = 526;
    graph.Item.Current.ItemType = "M";
    graph.Item.Current.ValMethod = "F";
    graph.Item.Current.TaxCategoryID = "TAXDEFAULT";
    graph.Item.Current.PostClassID = "INVDEFAULT";
    graph.Item.Current.LotSerClassID = "LOTSNDEFAU";
    graph.Item.Current.BaseUnit = "EA";
    graph.Item.Current.SalesUnit = "EA";
    graph.Item.Current.PurchaseUnit = "EA";

    graph.Item.Update(graph.Item.Current);

    graph.Actions.PressSave();
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Despite the error, the item still saves. I'm assuming the record is attempting to save more than once, but I'm not sure why.

EDIT:

Here is the trace for the error:

> > 11/7/2018 8:21:48 AM Error: 
> >     Error: Another process has added the 'InventoryItem' record. Your changes will >>be lost.
> >
> > at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row) 
> >       at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation) 
> >        at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation) 
> >        at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist() 
> >        at PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemMaint.Persist() in F:\Bld\AC-FULL2018R112-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\NonStockItemMaint.cs:line 2421 
> >        at JAMS.AEF.InventoryItemMaintAMExtension.Persist(Action del) 
> >        at CFBSModificationsTSC.VendorCatalog.convertToItem() in d:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\TexasScenic\App_RuntimeCode\VendorCatalog.cs:line 70 
> >        at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0(PXAdapter adapter) 
> >        at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0) 
> >        at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
> >        at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
> >        at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) 
> >        at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)

Comment: Please go to Help->Trace and show us the output - it will show us the full stack trace and maybe provide cues why your item is saving despite this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the CD value on the insert...

```
graph.Item.Current = graph.Item.Insert(new InventoryItem { InventoryCD = row.VendorPartID });
```

Then set the rest of your fields in the update as you have in your sample.

Comment: That worked! How would I know when I need to set the CD when inserting a new object for other object inserts? Just anytime there is a CD that isn't auto generated?

Comment: I pass in at least the keys in the insert (unless they are marked as defaulting from a parent). InventoryCD is actually marked as the key field for the InventoryItem dac and not InventoryID. Look for the IsKey on the dac which should help solve another process has inserted/updated messages.

Comment: Ahh didn't know the CD was the key and not the ID. Thanks.

Comment: yes it was a little bit of a curve ball. I just noticed myself and thought i would try to use the CD on the insert. Always good to review the iskeys when you get that type of message tho and then review how you are setting the keys on your insert, update